# Debugging WCF services in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging, w3wp

How can I tell which of my services is the one that I am trying to debug?

Using the Visual Studio 2010 debugger I would just look for the w3wp (or whatever the heck it was) that was running under the app pool username that my service was running under.

But now in my attach to processs window I have 3 msvmnon.exe processes and I don't see any wcf services running? What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What I wasn't doing was checking the show processes from all users.

[image: I am an imbecile]

Answer (score -1):

Set your WCF services project as startup in VS 2010. Then run the project, you will get a window with all services defined on the left side. Click on the service you wish to execute and pass parameters if any